# Correct approach for small static multilingual websites

Tags: html, multilingual

I'm creating for a client a small static website (5 pages), the plan is to have it in 4-5 different languages.
While looking for implementation advice I found lots of articles some of them more than 5 years old.

A few articles suggest using the .htaccess but I don't understand how it works. Other suggest to use PHP and an array containing the various translations.

I was leaning toward creating one directory per language each containing its own language version ( example.com/en, example.com/de, ...).
I would also have to implement the language selection for each page (independently of its language) something like

```
<a href="../en/page1.html"><img src="en-flag.jpg"></a>
<a href="../de/page1.html"><img src="de-flag.jpg"></a>
<a href="../es/page1.html"><img src="es-flag.jpg"></a>
```

And last it seems that I'll have to add for each page a block like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/en/page1.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de/page1.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://example.com/es/page1.html" />
```

Is this approach which seems straightforward in this context a terrible option ?

Comment: Please tell us a bit more about which frameworks you use on the back-end and front-end. Depending on this better solutions might exist. Creating a separate HTML page per language does not sound like the way to go.

Comment: @Mathyn since OP writes "a small static website", I'd guess there is no back-end at all, and there is no front-end framework being used.

Comment: @Stijn Right, that makes sense.

Comment: @Stijn Yes there's no backend/framework (no contact form either), I write the html/css by hand. I use VS Code and Gulp to automate some tasks

Comment: Of course the method you suggest isn't maintenance-friendly (a change in the HTML must be done for every page/language you create), but besides that it looks fine.

Comment: @Stijn I use gulp-inline-source to factorise the 'common' portions of code (nav bar, footer, common headers). Thanks for your answers.